# building apps in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I use a program in windows, but for some reason, I desperately need the program to be running in Ubuntu. I have downloaded the source code, but didn't know what to do next.

I contacted the developer and he said that "You must rebuild it from sources and ask google about building Qt apps".

How to develop using Qt?

Version:Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: What is the name of the program?

Comment: SanDic   [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sandic/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much information, but depending on the program, you should give wine a try, or virtual box.

With Wine you can run Windows programs under Ubuntu. That is not always possible and sometimes extremely buggy. Install Wine from the softwarecenter. Then right click on .exe-file - open with wine.

Virtual box installs Windows in Ubuntu and then you can install the program inside. That is very comfortable, because it runs as a normal program window on your Ubuntu Desktop. Install virtualbox from the softwarecenter. Install Windows inside (you will need your installation CD). Install program as usual in Windows.

Comment: I tried wine but it was of no use